# Linux: Allow one user to manage all files from another user/group

Tags: linux, permissions, lamp, permission-denied, ubuntu-12.04

I just installed `lamp-server^` on my home linux machine. 
Now I created a new folder `project` with files in the `/var/www/` directory (server root directory). I set the owner user/group to `www-data` via `sudo`.

Now I want to access the folder and its files via `cd` or normally via the file explorer, but I get the error that I haven't the permission to do/access that folder or its files (with my normal user account).

Is it possible to give my user account the rights to access/modify the `project` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can either

a+rwx the directory or

include yourself in that group, but from your question, it seems you don't want to do that. it would be more secure than allowing anyone to read, write and execute that dir.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Just add your user in www-data group.

```
useradd -G www-data {your_username}
```